# What does Martial arcanist mean for gaining spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

I was a bit confused by the wording for Martial Arcanist.

> Martial Arcanist (Ex): At 5th level, you master the art of combining your militant and mystical training. From this point on, your caster level in a chosen arcane spellcast- ing class is equal to your base attack bonus (unless it would otherwise be higher). For example, a 7th-level fighter/1st-level wizard/5th-level abjurant champion has a base attack bonus of +12 (and thus a caster level of 12th). You can apply this benefit to only one arcane class to which you have added spellcasting levels by your advancement as an abjurant champion.

Does this mean, if I were a sorcerer 1 fighter 5 abj champ 5 that I'd have the spells of an 11th level sorcerer? Or does it mean I just get bonuses relating to caster level (like having more magic missiles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martial Arcanist only applies to caster level, as it says in the ability description.  Caster level determines things like how much damage your *fireball*s do, and doesn't affect your spells per day or spells known at all.

A Sor 1/Abj 5/Fighter 5 would have a caster level of 10, and would have spells per day and spells known of a 6th level Sorcerer.